# Any pattern to remove these if else?

Tags: python, design-patterns

```
# status.py

class Status(object):

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, title, kind, attachment):
        self.db.set('title', title)
        self.db.set('kind', kind)
        self.db.set('attachment', attachment)


def add_text_status(title, text):
    Status.add(title, 'text', {
        'text': text
    })

def add_photo_status(title, photos):
    Status.add(title, 'photos', {
        'photos': photos
    })

def add_video_status(title, video_url):
    Status.add(title, 'video', {
        'url': video_url  
    })

...

# view.py

@app.route('/add')
def add_status(request):
    title = request.get('title')
    kind = request.get('kind')
    if kind == 'text':
        text = request.get('text')
        status = add_text_status(title, kind, text)
    elif kind == 'photos':
        photo_ids = request.get('photo_ids')
        photos = Photo.gets(photo_ids)
        status = add_photo_status(title, kind, photos)
    elif kind == 'video':
        video_url = request.get('video_url')
        status = add_video_status(title, kind, video_url)
    elif ....

    return status.to_json()
```

Hi, is there any method to improve this code by removing the `if elif elif elif` codes in the `view.py`?

Comment: Not without seeing the rest of them.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've added another to make it three of them

Answer (score 6):

You can use a method dispatch:

```
def process_text_status(request, title):
    text = request.get('text')
    status = add_text_status(title, kind, text)

def process_photo_status(request, title):
    photo_ids = request.get('photo_ids')
    photos = Photo.gets(photo_ids)
    status = add_photo_status(title, kind, photos)


process_kind_status = {
    'text': process_text_status,
    'photos': process_photo_status,
}

@app.route('/add')
def add_status(request):
    title = request.get('title')
    kind = request.get('kind')
    process_kind_status[kind](request, title)
```

or merge the `process_*_status` functionality into `add_*_status`.